# Selecting only those rows froom a matrix when an attribute in a column matches a given condition in Eigen, c++

Tags: c++, matrix, slice, eigen, eigen3

Suppose I have a matrix A (4x4):

```
1,2,3,0
4,5,6,0
7,8,9,1
1,3,4,1
```

I want to create a new matrix say matrix B whose rows are all the rows of A such that the 4th column of A has a value of 0.
Here my B matrix should be:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

How can I do that in Eigen?

Comment: Use block() method of matrix. Template parameters are new matrix size, Method parameters are start position of column and row

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < MATRIX_SIZE; rowNumber++)
{
    if(rowNumber == 2){
       break;
    }
    // do something with this row
    for(int colNumber = 0; colNumber < MATRIX_SIZE; colNumber++)
    {
        if(colNumber == 3){
          break;
        }
        // do something with this row
    }
}
```